# What process should a programmer follow to convert a complex Object into serializable?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I am attempting to follow the advice from this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8102/Saving-and-obtaining-custom-objects-to-from-Window

After reading that, I naively concluded:

"Ah! all I have to do is hunt the offending locations in **my code**, and mark them as `[Serializable]`. That is easy enough."

Notice the 2 error messages that I am getting, one from my application and the larger one from the CodeProject's `IsSerializable()` Method:

[Images Blocked by stackoverflow Site]

http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Not-Serializable-More.png

This code is preventing my object from being serialized:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class DisplayItem : PropertyChangedBase
{
}
```

I marked my class `DisplayItem` but how on earth am I support to mark Microsoft's class `PropertyChangedBase`??

TIA.

Comment: You can't change that. You'll need an adapter clas to hold your DisplayItem state and after serialization recreate the actual DisplayItem class.

Comment: Is this "adapter" class some sort of special class, or your just chose that word to describe its functionality?

Comment: No, it is not a special class, just a description of the pattern to use....